# API equivalent to etc/hosts?

Tags: winapi, dns, device-driver, hosts

Is there a Windows (or Windows Device Driver) API that's equivalent to editing the etc/hosts file, i.e. to override or change the hostname-to-IPaddress mapping?

I'd want for a scenario where DNS might not exist on a LAN, or where the hosts in question aren't known to DNS, but where I know the host name and the IP addresses.

If not, then I take it that editing etc/hosts programmatically is the only way to do this?

How often or how soon does an edit to etc/hosts take effect -- i.e. if I edit it then will my next network connection request to a given host name use the new IP address, or is a stale value cached somewhere?

Comment: Anecdote not a real answer: manually editing has always taken effect immediately  for new processes in my experience.  Some already running processes might be caching DNS responses on their own (if written to do that) and using raw IPs, but I haven't seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the file `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` which is exactly equivalent to the *nix `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Yes my question was whether there's a Windows API equivalent to (i.e. instead of) editing that file.

Comment: I am certainly not aware of any API method of doing so. I suspect that if there is one it would be found buried somewhere in WMI.